# maas juju how to power on a node

Tags: 14.04, server, juju, maas, cloud

I am not getting the answer anywhere.  Do I need to manually turn on the nodes ? or nodes will be turned on automatically ? if its automatic then what is the trigger ? and how will I shut down ?

A ready node can be allocated through "Start Node" button in maas panel. as well as with juju. what is the different between them ?

https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/nodes.html mentions

> With nodes set to boot from a PXE image, they will start, look for a DHCP server, receive the PXE boot details, boot the image, contact the MAAS server and shut down.

Is the any button in maas panel to accept the node ? I do `maas maas nodes accept-all` that returns `[]`. Do I still need to accept the node ? would the node still get restarted ?

Do I need to install juju on all nodes ?

How do I re-bootstrap after adding a new node in maas which is in "Declared" state.

Answer (score 1):

Before you start playing with Juju, check your MAAS correct function.

Each time you add a new node in MAAS GUI and hit commision node, it should automaticaly boot the machine (node), run the commisioning scripts and then it will turn off the node with Ready state.

You can do this as many times as you want and this way you can check that MAAS is able to power on the node remotely, via PXE.

Once this works, you can call command

> juju add-machine *node_with_name_in_maaas*

this will force to power up the node, install ubuntu server, change the state to Allocated to ___ and then you can deploy charms on it..

Comment: Once the Node has been allocated by juju can I manually power up or down the node ?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this doesn't really answer your question, I have had similar problems with my MAAS setup and it might help you to know what I have been doing.

I haven't been able to get juju to complete the bootstrap process yet, so in the meantime I have been doing the following:

#### Start node through MAAS GUI

Go to the 'nodes' page in the MAAS web interface. For nodes with a 'Ready' state, you can tick their boxes and then then choose 'start selected nodes'  from the bulk action drop down menu.

WARNING: If I then use this process to 'stop' selected nodes and then 'start' them again, they are re-imaged, thus losing all existing data!

#### Starting and Stopping with amttool

Through the nodes page on the MAAS web interface you can get to a page which shows you the 'power parameters' for a given node. In my case the physical nodes are using AMT and have an associated IP address (which is not the same as the IP address of the node). I can then use:

```
amttool [Power IP Address] powerup

amttool [Power IP Address] powerdown
```

This is what I am using at the moment. I would love to know of other options.